# How to call a function in another function in Python?

Tags: python

I am learning this Python, and I am new to it.
I was solving a question which goes like this:

Q1.)Write a Python function, evalQuadratic(a, b, c, x), that returns the value of the quadratic a*x**2+*⋅x+c.
This function takes in four numbers and returns a single number.
My solution:

```
def evalQuadratic(a, b, c, x):
    '''
    a, b, c: numerical values for the coefficients of a quadratic equation
    x: numerical value at which to evaluate the quadratic.
    '''
    return ((a*(x*x))+(b*x)+c)
```

Now this part is fine.
There is one more question, which goes like this:

Q2.)Write a Python function, twoQuadratics, that takes in two sets of coefficients and x-values and prints the sum of the results of evaluating two quadratic equations. It does not do anything else. That is, you should evaluate and print the result of the following equation: a1∗x1**2+b1∗x1+c1+a2∗x2**2+b2∗x2+c2
You should use the evalQuadratic function you defined in the "Quadratic" problem of these exercises (you don't need to redefine evalQuadratic in this box; when you call evalQuadratic, our definition will be used).

My Solution:

```
def twoQuadratics(a1, b1, c1, x1, a2, b2, c2, x2):
    '''
    a1, b1, c1: one set of coefficients of a quadratic equation
    a2, b2, c2: another set of coefficients of a quadratic equation
    x1, x2: values at which to evaluate the quadratics
    '''
    for i in range(2):
        return evalQuadratic(a1, b1, c1, x1) + evalQuadratic(a2, b2 ,c2, x2)
```

I don't know whats wrong with the code, actually its working fine on Canopy IDE on my PC, but returns nothing in the online editor, where I need to give the solution.

Comment: Did you also add the `evalQuadratic()` function in the online editor?

Comment: Why have you got a for loop?

Comment: you defined a loop certainly to index your variables (which is not necessary) and you do not use i ...

Comment: by the way the problem is unclear since in your comment you say you wanna evaluate the second function in x21, x1 for the first call to evalQuadratic (but it's not what is coded) ... some clarification would be great.

Comment: You've not stated a clear question here. Please ask a very specific question, after first describing the output and behaviour of your code. Finally, it looks like the issue requires your school's online form to reproduce. You should ask them for help.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem in your IDE, how do you expect others to do so?

Comment: @barny Yeah that for loop is not actually required, code is working in my IDE by just returning the last line. But in the online IDE its not working.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel This is my first question here on stack Overflow, I am very new to it.
Test Values: a1 = -3.58, b1 = 8.34, c1 = -4.11, x1 = -7.78, a2 = 4.49, b2 = 0.44, c2 = -5.34, x2 = -0.78
Your output:
Correct output:
-288.638356

Test Values: a1 = -3.17, b1 = 1.16, c1 = -9.32, x1 = -4.25, a2 = 0.33, b2 = -3.91, c2 = 5.24, x2 = 3.18
Your output:
Correct output:
-75.364833
These are few of the test performed by the online IDE on my code and the code returns nothing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What do you mean?? I did not get you. I am saying its working on my IDE(Canopy) but it returns nothing on the online IDE.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yup, that that was done itself by the online IDE.

Comment: I mean there's no problem when you try it in your IDE, so what makes you think that someone else will have a problem with it in their IDE? This question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Your spec says:

> Write a Python function, twoQuadratics, that takes in two sets of coefficients and x-values and **prints** the sum of the results of evaluating two quadratic equations

Notice the term : it's "prints", not "returns", so what is expected here is very certainly:

```
def twoQuadratics(a1, b1, c1, x1, a2, b2, c2, x2):
    print(evalQuadratic(a1, b1, c1, x1) + evalQuadratic(a2, b2 ,c2, x2))
```

Comment: How can i be so careless...... damn!!!
Thanks Bruno.. thank you very much.
I want to upvote your answer but i can't i dont't have enough ruputation.
And do you think asking this question here was not right like few people who downvoted my question, its not that i didn't tried i had the solution, but there was some carelesness, i agree.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can take input as a list of dict so your function will be. So your function will be more generic.

```
enter [{
  'a':2,
  'b':3,
  'c':5,
  'x':10,
 },
 {
   'a':4,
   'b':7,
   'c':5,
   'x':10,
 }]
def my_fun(co_list):
  sum = 0
  for co in co_list:
    sum = sum + evalQuadratic(co['a'], co['b'], co['c'], co['x'])
return sum here
```

Comment: Not only does this not solve the issue, it's not syntactically valid.